# shows white stable popup after running application on third party application

Tags: c#

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nKJaN.png)please help me to solve this .

i am using windows 7 for development with vs2010, have one application(wpf) which is running proper with click on .exe, but when i used to call same by some third-party application which is made by using win Xp- service pack -03, shows white stable popup which is not movable and appearance till application closed, other all functionalities of application runs smoothly only this popup appearance.

Comment: can you put in the code you tried?

Comment: i have add snapshots please refer .

Comment: Please post the relevant code so it can be reviewed, just the description and a screenshot is not enough information

Comment: i don't have code for the third party app used , and one more thing if new fresh application is created without coding also shows same.